# Using $this within $.ajax inside a function of success

Tags: jquery

When I use the line below, $(this) inside my jQuery function (example below) it works great.

```
$(this).closest('.item').children('h3').children('a').text('UPDATED');
```

However, inside the same function I try to then move it within a function of success: area of $.ajax and it no longer works. I've checked that the success function works with an alert.

Is there a way to preserve the scope of $(this) inside $.ajax?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Problem area:

```
success : function(msg){
$(this).closest('.item').children('h3').children('a').text('UPDATED');
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use context:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function () {
        $(this)...
    },
    context: this // or whatever this is
})
```

Look up the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option about 14% down the page.

Comment: I know. tt's not very well known. Full disclosure, I found out about it because of a stack overflow question.

Comment: @JoeTuskan: are there more functions with context option ?

Comment: @Martin, yes. It's using https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply in the background to invoke the callbacks.

Comment: Thanks @JoeTuskan, I really appreciate it. Embarrassed to say I had that docs page opened, but just didn't get what it did at first.

Answer (score 2):

You're searching for wrong `$(this)` (in wrong context). Do something like

```
$(".button").click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.ajax({
        success: function() {
             // $this is $(this) you need
             $this.closest('.item').children('h3').children('a').text('UPDATED');
        }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign `$(this)` to a variable.

```
var $myThis = $(this);
// ajax stuff
success: function(msg){
   $myThis.closest('.item').children('h3').children('a').text('UPDATED');
}
```